Finding the derivative with the chain rule given mutually dependent variables
This might be a banal problem. If so, I apologize. But I had problems in coming to a conclusion. We set $\theta := \frac{1}{\epsilon} \tau.$ We are given a function of two variables $\eta = \eta (\theta(\tau), \tau).$ I need to compute the derivative $\frac{d\eta}{d\theta}.$ Given the mutual (linear) dependence of the variables $\theta, \tau,$ I have some doubts. I am wondering if the result should be $\frac{d\eta}{d\theta} = \frac{\partial\eta}{\partial\theta} + \frac{\partial\eta}{\partial\tau}\frac{d\tau}{d\theta} = \frac{\partial\eta}{\partial\theta} + \epsilon \frac{\partial\eta}{\partial\tau}$ or $\frac{d\eta}{d\theta} = \frac{\partial\eta}{\partial\theta}.$ The doubt lies in the tact that given $\theta(\tau) = \frac{1}{\epsilon} \tau,$ we may also write this as $\tau(\theta) = \epsilon \theta.$ Does the result depend on how one expresses the function, i.e. $\eta = \eta(\theta(\tau), \tau)$ vs. $\eta = \eta(\theta, \tau(\theta))$ ?

Of course, the last two functions differ significantly. Assume, for example,  that $\eta$ is simply the sum of the arguments and write down both functions.

In such cases, it is sometimes convenient to write numbers for partial derivatives, instead of variables, so as not to be confused when we have a variable and when we have a function. For example, for $\eta(\theta, \tau(\theta))$ write $\eta'_1$ in place $ \frac{\partial\eta}{\partial\theta}$.

From a modern mathematical perspective, there are three functions being called $\eta$ here: the original 2D function, and the distinct 1D functions $$"\eta" = H_1(\theta) := \eta(\theta, \tau(\theta)) = \eta(\theta, \epsilon\theta)$$ and $$"\eta" = H_2(\tau) := \eta(\theta(\tau), \tau) =\eta(\tau /\epsilon, \tau)$$The notation$\frac{d\eta}{d\theta}$ indicates we are wanting $\eta$ as a function of the first coordinate $\theta$ instead of the second $\tau$. I.e. $H_1$, not $H_2$.
